# Why is my External flash not working?

Tags: canon, flash, yongnuo

I recently bought a canon eos 200d and I also bought an Yongnuo YN24EX twin flash however when my camera is on M mode it does not work, but it works on AV mode.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need a LOT more details from you about how your flashes are connected to the camera and what settings you have selected for a large number of variables before we can even begin to diagnose what the problem is. As asked, it could any one of dozens of things

Comment: What Tv ("shutter speed") is selected when shooting in "M" exposure mode? What Tv does the camera select when shooting in Av mode? Does your 200D have the large center contact in its hot shoe, or is it missing? (Some 200D bodies have it, some don't.)

Comment: @MichaelC, the 200D is the SL2. It has the sync contact; it's the 250D (SL3) that's missing the sync contact.

Comment: In M mode, in the camera's flash control menu, how is **Flash firing** set? And by "does not work" do you mean it doesn't fire? Only one side fires? Fires at the wrong time? TTL isn't adjusting power properly, etc.